# Trying to scan values with scanf within a loop. Requires secondary input to print the first input

Tags: c, while-loop, user-input, scanf

I'm having trouble with scanf (and before anyone mentions it, I have to use it. I can't use `getchar()`, `fgets()`, and various other things). In my code below, I need to add (or subtract) two real numbers or integers, and store the sum to memory. I think I can sort out the memory stuff myself, but the problem is with printing the result of the sum.

I have to type '6+6', press enter, and then input another character for the original sum to be displayed. Also if I type '6+6+' the program acts I want it to.

I imagine I've made a very basic error. I'm very tired.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char memoryExitSwitch[256];
  int q =1;
  double operandOneHalf;
  double operandTwo;
  double result = 0.0;

  while(q == 1){
    scanf("%lf"  "%lf ", &operandOneHalf, &operandTwo);
    scanf( " %s", memoryExitSwitch);

    switch (memoryExitSwitch[0]) {
      case 'p':
        result = memoryExitSwitch[1] + operandTwo;
        printf("ANS1= %lf\n", result);
        memoryExitSwitch[1] = result;
        break;

      case 'q':
        q = 0;
        break;

      default:
        result = operandOneHalf + operandTwo;
        printf("ANS2= %lf\n", result);
        memoryExitSwitch[1] =  result;
        break;
    }//switch

  }//main while loop q
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing out `memoryExitSwitch` before the switch statement?

Comment: You've got a trailing blank in the format string of the first `svanf()`; that's a major problem.  It doesn't stop until you type a non-blank.

Answer (score 2):

Various problems

1. The trailing space `"%lf "`  obliges `scanf()` to detect following non-white-space after the number, delaying `scanf()` return.  [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968870/trying-to-scan-values-with-scanf-within-a-loop-requires-secondary-input-to-prin/39969571#comment67217567_39968870).  The `" "` says to consume all optional following white-space.  `scanf()` needs to see some non-white-space to know it has seen all the following white-space.

   ```
   // scanf("%lf"  "%lf ", &operandOneHalf, &operandTwo);
   //                   v--- no space
   if (scanf("%lf"  "%lf", &operandOneHalf, &operandTwo) != 2) return -1;
   ```
2. Good code limits the input width to prevent buffer overflow

   ```
   char memoryExitSwitch[256];
   // scanf( " %s", memoryExitSwitch);
   //          v ---- space not needed
   //          |255 - lit input to 1 less than buffer size
   //          | |                           v--- Check result
   if (scanf( "%255s", memoryExitSwitch) != 1) return -1;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your program waits for a non-whitespace character after the second number, because of the trailing space after the second `%lf` here:

```
scanf("%lf"  "%lf ", &operandOneHalf, &operandTwo);
```

..and if you fix that, it will *still* wait for a non-whitespace string to be input after the two numbers, because of the following call to `scanf()`:

```
scanf( " %s", memoryExitSwitch);
```

Comment: Not that one; it's the other one that's the trouble.

Comment: "Your program waits for a non-whitespace string "  --> `scanf( " %s", memoryExitSwitch);` has the same effect as `scanf( "%s", memoryExitSwitch);`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's *both* of them that are the trouble.  If the space after `%lf` is fixed then the following `scanf()` will still wait for a string to satisfy `%s`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, and both of them wait for some non-whitespace to satisfy `%s`.

Comment: Actually, no.  It's the first one that's the main trouble.  It doesn't complete until the user types some character that's not white space.  Yes, there also has to be a white space of some form (e.g. a newline) after the character that terminated the first input, but the primary problem is still the first `scanf()`.  You can type as many newlines, tabs and blanks as you please and the first one still doesn't complete.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sure but if you fix the first one so that it doesn't require a non-whitespace character to complete, the second `scanf()` *will still require at least one non-whitespace character to complete*.  The second `scanf()` is called unconditionally after the first one, so fixing the first one alone **will not fix the problem**.